# WPF Blurry Images - Bitmap Class

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, bitmap

I am using the following sample at http://blogs.msdn.com/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx within VB.NET.  The code is shown below.

I am having a problem when my application loads the CPU is pegging 50-70%.  I have determined that the problem is with the `Bitmap` class.  The `OnLayoutUpdated()` method is calling the `InvalidateVisual()` continously.  This is because some points are not returning as equal but rather, `Point(0.0,-0.5)`

Can anyone see any bugs within this code or know a better implmentation for pixel snapping a Bitmap image so it is not blurry?

p.s. The sample code was in C#, however I believe that it was converted correctly.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging

Class Bitmap Inherits FrameworkElement
' Use FrameworkElement instead of UIElement so Data Binding works as expected

Private _sourceDownloaded As EventHandler
Private _sourceFailed As EventHandler(Of ExceptionEventArgs)
Private _pixelOffset As Windows.Point

Public Sub New()
    _sourceDownloaded = New EventHandler(AddressOf OnSourceDownloaded)
    _sourceFailed = New EventHandler(Of ExceptionEventArgs)(AddressOf OnSourceFailed)

    AddHandler LayoutUpdated, AddressOf OnLayoutUpdated
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly SourceProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", GetType(BitmapSource), GetType(Bitmap), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender Or FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf Bitmap.OnSourceChanged)))

Public Property Source() As BitmapSource
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(SourceProperty), BitmapSource)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As BitmapSource)
        SetValue(SourceProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Function FindParentWindow(ByVal child As DependencyObject) As Window
    Dim parent As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child)

    'Check if this is the end of the tree
    If parent Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim parentWindow As Window = TryCast(parent, Window)
    If parentWindow IsNot Nothing Then
        Return parentWindow
    Else
        ' Use recursion until it reaches a Window
        Return FindParentWindow(parent)
    End If
End Function

Public Event BitmapFailed As EventHandler(Of ExceptionEventArgs)

' Return our measure size to be the size needed to display the bitmap pixels.
'
' Use MeasureOverride instead of MeasureCore so Data Binding works as expected.
' Protected Overloads Overrides Function MeasureCore(ByVal availableSize As Size) As Size
Protected Overloads Overrides Function MeasureOverride(ByVal availableSize As Size) As Size
    Dim measureSize As New Size()

    Dim bitmapSource As BitmapSource = Source
    If bitmapSource IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim ps As PresentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Me)
        If Me.VisualParent IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim window As Window = window.GetWindow(Me.VisualParent)
            If window IsNot Nothing Then
                ps = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window.GetWindow(Me.VisualParent))
            ElseIf FindParentWindow(Me) IsNot Nothing Then
                ps = PresentationSource.FromVisual(FindParentWindow(Me))
            End If
        End If
        '
        If ps IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim fromDevice As Matrix = ps.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice

            Dim pixelSize As New Vector(bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight)
            Dim measureSizeV As Vector = fromDevice.Transform(pixelSize)
            measureSize = New Size(measureSizeV.X, measureSizeV.Y)
        Else
            measureSize = New Size(bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight)
        End If
    End If

    Return measureSize
End Function

Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnRender(ByVal dc As DrawingContext)
    Dim bitmapSource As BitmapSource = Me.Source
    If bitmapSource IsNot Nothing Then
        _pixelOffset = GetPixelOffset()

        ' Render the bitmap offset by the needed amount to align to pixels.
        dc.DrawImage(bitmapSource, New Rect(_pixelOffset, DesiredSize))
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnSourceChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim bitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(d, Bitmap)

    Dim oldValue As BitmapSource = DirectCast(e.OldValue, BitmapSource)
    Dim newValue As BitmapSource = DirectCast(e.NewValue, BitmapSource)

    If ((oldValue IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (bitmap._sourceDownloaded IsNot Nothing)) AndAlso (Not oldValue.IsFrozen AndAlso (TypeOf oldValue Is BitmapSource)) Then
        RemoveHandler DirectCast(oldValue, BitmapSource).DownloadCompleted, bitmap._sourceDownloaded
        RemoveHandler DirectCast(oldValue, BitmapSource).DownloadFailed, bitmap._sourceFailed
        ' ((BitmapSource)newValue).DecodeFailed -= bitmap._sourceFailed; // 3.5
    End If
    If ((newValue IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (TypeOf newValue Is BitmapSource)) AndAlso Not newValue.IsFrozen Then
        AddHandler DirectCast(newValue, BitmapSource).DownloadCompleted, bitmap._sourceDownloaded
        AddHandler DirectCast(newValue, BitmapSource).DownloadFailed, bitmap._sourceFailed
        ' ((BitmapSource)newValue).DecodeFailed += bitmap._sourceFailed; // 3.5
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub OnSourceDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    InvalidateMeasure()
    InvalidateVisual()
End Sub

Private Sub OnSourceFailed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ExceptionEventArgs)
    Source = Nothing
    ' setting a local value seems scetchy...
    RaiseEvent BitmapFailed(Me, e)
End Sub

Private Sub OnLayoutUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' This event just means that layout happened somewhere. However, this is
    ' what we need since layout anywhere could affect our pixel positioning.
    Dim pixelOffset As Windows.Point = GetPixelOffset()
    If Not AreClose(pixelOffset, _pixelOffset) Then
        InvalidateVisual()
    End If
End Sub

' Gets the matrix that will convert a Windows.Point from "above" the
' coordinate space of a visual into the the coordinate space
' "below" the visual.
Private Function GetVisualTransform(ByVal v As Visual) As Matrix
    If v IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim m As Matrix = Matrix.Identity

        Dim transform As Transform = VisualTreeHelper.GetTransform(v)
        If transform IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim cm As Matrix = transform.Value
            m = Matrix.Multiply(m, cm)
        End If

        Dim offset As Vector = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(v)
        m.Translate(offset.X, offset.Y)

        Return m
    End If

    Return Matrix.Identity
End Function

Private Function TryApplyVisualTransform(ByVal Point As Windows.Point, ByVal v As Visual, ByVal inverse As Boolean, ByVal throwOnError As Boolean, ByRef success As Boolean) As Windows.Point
    success = True
    If v IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim visualTransform As Matrix = GetVisualTransform(v)
        If inverse Then
            If Not throwOnError AndAlso Not visualTransform.HasInverse Then
                success = False
                Return New Windows.Point(0, 0)
            End If
            visualTransform.Invert()
        End If
        Point = visualTransform.Transform(Point)
    End If
    Return Point
End Function

Private Function ApplyVisualTransform(ByVal Point As Windows.Point, ByVal v As Visual, ByVal inverse As Boolean) As Windows.Point
    Dim success As Boolean = True
    Return TryApplyVisualTransform(Point, v, inverse, True, success)
End Function

Private Function GetPixelOffset() As Windows.Point
    Dim pixelOffset As New Windows.Point()

    Dim ps As PresentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Me)
    If ps IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim rootVisual As Visual = ps.RootVisual

        ' Transform (0,0) from this element up to pixels.
        pixelOffset = Me.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual).Transform(pixelOffset)
        pixelOffset = ApplyVisualTransform(pixelOffset, rootVisual, False)
        pixelOffset = ps.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.Transform(pixelOffset)

        ' Round the origin to the nearest whole pixel.
        pixelOffset.X = Math.Round(pixelOffset.X)
        pixelOffset.Y = Math.Round(pixelOffset.Y)

        ' Transform the whole-pixel back to this element.
        pixelOffset = ps.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(pixelOffset)
        pixelOffset = ApplyVisualTransform(pixelOffset, rootVisual, True)
        pixelOffset = rootVisual.TransformToDescendant(Me).Transform(pixelOffset)

    End If

    Return pixelOffset
End Function

Private Function AreClose(ByVal Point1 As Windows.Point, ByVal Point2 As Windows.Point) As Boolean
    Return AreClose(Point1.X, Point2.X) AndAlso AreClose(Point1.Y, Point2.Y)
End Function

Private Function AreClose(ByVal value1 As Double, ByVal value2 As Double) As Boolean
    If value1 = value2 Then
        Return True
    End If
    Dim delta As Double = value1 - value2
    Return ((delta < 0.00000153) AndAlso (delta > -0.00000153))
End Function


End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider trying a new property available now in **WPF4**. Leave the `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` to *HighQuality* or just don't declare it.

*NearestNeighbor* worked for me except it led to jaggy bitmaps when zooming in on the application. It also didn't seem to fix any glitches where icons were sizing in weird ways.

On your root element (i.e. your main window) add this property: `UseLayoutRounding="True"`.

A property previously only available in Silverlight has now fixed all Bitmap sizing woes. :)

An older code fix you may want to check is found below.

---

Nir from **Nbd-Tech** posted this some time ago in this post: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/11/20/blurred-images-in-wpf.aspx

Replace the MeasureCore method in the Bitmap class with this code:

```
protected override Size MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size measureSize = new Size();

        BitmapSource bitmapSource = Source;
        if(bitmapSource != null)
        {
            measureSize = new Size(bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight);
        }

        return measureSize;
    }
```

Comment: More info found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First of all never hook OnLayoutUpdated, it's a memory hog.

This is how I prevent blurry bitmap in Xaml and it works :D, make sure your bitmap are saved at 96 dpi in your image editing program.

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource img}" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
       Width="16"
       Height="16"
       gi:ImageGreyer.IsGreyable="True"/>
```